# I get an error when read txt file in my app

Tags: android

Thanks for your time ,when my app run at line `mycode = "UTF-8"`and it jump directly to the catch.It's very strange because I only set values to the string mycode.furthermore when I read txt files that are coded by ANSI,values of `head[0]`,`head[1]` and `head[2]`are not ``` -17``-69 ```and`-65`,so the condition supposed to be dissatisfy.but the fact is app still execute the sentence`mycode = "UTF-8"`.I can't figure out the reason ,any help will be appreciate.

my code is below:

```
package com.example.tyghgy;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.util.Log;

public class MyTxt {

    private BufferedReader br = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    public MyTxt(){
          File f=null;
          f= new File("/sdcard/s.txt");
          String sssss;

          try {
           in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
           sssss = get_code();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e3.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8"));
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
          }


    }


    private String get_code(){
        String mycode = "";  
        byte[] head = new byte[3];  
        try{
        in.read(head);  

        if (head[0] == -1 && head[1] == -2 )  
            mycode = "UTF-16";  
        if (head[0] == -2 && head[1] == -1 )  
            mycode = "Unicode";  
        if(head[0]==-17 && head[1]==-69 && head[2] ==-65)  
            mycode = "UTF-8";  

        return mycode;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.v("sssssssssss", e.getMessage());
            mycode = e.getMessage();
            return mycode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the logcat logs....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` for getting path of SDCARD as:

```
String sdcardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fName = "s.txt";
File f = new File(sdcardpath + File.separator + fName);
//Your Code...
```

And also make sure you have added following permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```